# How do I create a Flatbutton in flutter with 2 color? not gradient, 2 solid color side by side

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, flatbutton

How do I create a Flatbutton in flutter with 2 colors? not gradient, 2 solid color side by side.
[image]

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want?

Comment: updated a picture

Comment: a hint: use both `colors` and `stops` parameters of the [LinearGradient constructor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/LinearGradient/LinearGradient.html)

Comment: @pskink any example?

Comment: `colors: [Colors.orange, Colors.red, Colors.red, Colors.green],
      stops: [0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.5],`

Answer (score 2):

might be a shorter answer using gradient and stops

```
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors:  [Colors.red, Theme.of(context).buttonColor] 
              stops: [0.5, 0.5]
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
```

Comment: you mean `stops: [0.5, 0.5]` ? the docs say: *"The values in the stops list must be in ascending order. If a value in the stops list is less than an earlier value in the list, then its value is assumed to equal the previous value."* - so please use *"ascending order"*

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. You can tweak it to meet your needs

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 100,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.red)),
                Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.blue)),
              ],
            ),
            Center(child: Text('PRESS ME')),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```